# Every plane intersects set between $1$ and $5$ points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Does there exist a set of points in the $3$-dimensional space such that every plane intersects this set in at least $1$ point but at most $5$ points?

For any fixed $k\in\mathbb{R}$, we can consider the plane covering points $(x,y,k)$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, so at least one and at most five such points are in the set. Similarly for planes $(x,k,z)$ and $(k,y,z)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider set:

$$\mathcal{C}=\{(t,t^3,t^5):t \in \mathbb{R}\}$$

You know that every plane has equation $Ax+By+Cz=D$ for some $A,B,C,D$. Now for point of intersection $\mathcal{C}$ and plane:

$$At+Bt^3+Ct^5=D$$

This equation has at least one real solution (odd degree polynomial if $C \neq 0$ or $C=0$ and $B\neq 0$ or $C=B=0$ and $A \neq 0$) and at most 5 solution by Fundamental Theorem of Algebra. One root of this equation gives only one point in $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: You really don't need the fundamental theorem of algebra to see it has at most 5 solutions, that's quite trivial.